# Position fixed elements in Android are positioned slight incorrectly

Tags: android, css

In Android specifically, when I open a new view (going from display none to display block), my toolbar (just a plain old div) is position fixed and it is incorrectly positioned about 2px from the top and the left.

Sometimes after 500ms it will jump into correct position (0px, 0px). Sometimes it stays incorrectly positioned.

I've tried a number of things including hiding and the showing it.

Any hacks to fix this seemingly inherit Android browser bug?

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the absolute layout? That has been deprecated; instead - use a combination of linear and relative layouts, depending on your need. You can then use android:paddingLeft and android:paddingTop in the XML attributes in order to move the widget how you explained.